# Smash product of spheres in $\mathbf{SH}$ and product in cohomology

Tags: stable-homotopy, stable-homotopy-category, motivic-homotopy, simplicial-presheaves

I have two very concrete and simple question. Just in case I write downwards what led me into this.

My questions: Let $\mathbf{SH}(X)$ be the stable homotopy category of Voevodsky. Denote $S^n$ the simplicial $n$-sphere and also the spectrum it defines by infinite suspension.

1.- **Is the following diagram commutative?**
$$
\begin{matrix}
S^a\wedge S^{b}&\buildrel{\sim}\over{\to} & S^{a+b}\\
\sigma \downarrow  & &\downarrow ^{(-1)^{a+b}}\\
S^b\wedge S^a &\buildrel{\sim}\over{\to} & S^{a+b}
\end{matrix}
$$
where $\sigma$ denotes the permutation.

2.- If so, **can you give a proof or a concrete reference?**

Thanks in advance.

---

What led me to this question? Recall from [Cisinki and Deglise](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.3291v3.pdf) that the algebraic de Rham cohomology is represented by a **commutative** ring spectrum $E_{\mathrm{dR}}$, in other words:
$$
H^p(X,\Omega_X^\bullet)=\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{SH(X)_\mathbb{Q}}}(1_X,E_{\mathrm{dR}}[p]).
$$
Note that commutative spectrum means that there is a product $\mu \colon E\wedge E\to E$ satisfying the commutative diagram if we switch the source. We know that the algebraic de Rham cohomology is **anticommutative** or **graded commutative**, (because the product comes from the wedge product on differential forms) In other words, $\alpha \in H^p(X,\Omega_X^\bullet)$ and $\beta \in H^q(X,\Omega_X^\bullet)$ then $\alpha \cdot \beta =(-1)^{p+q}\beta\cdot \alpha$.

Let me recall the definition of product in the $E$-cohomology. Let $\alpha\in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{SH(X)_\mathbb{Q}}}(1_X,E_{\mathrm{dR}}[p])$ and $\beta \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{SH(X)_\mathbb{Q}}}(1_X,E_{\mathrm{dR}}[p'])$, then 
$$
\alpha\cdot \beta \colon 1_X\to E_{\mathrm{dR}}[p]\wedge E_{\mathrm{dR}}[p']\simeq E_{\mathrm{dR}}\wedge E_{\mathrm{dR}}\wedge 1_X[p+p']\buildrel{\mu}\over{\longrightarrow}E_{\mathrm{dR}}\wedge 1_X[p+p']\simeq E_{\mathrm{dR}}[p+p']
$$
Recall that $1_X[p]=S^p\wedge 1_X$, in order for this product to be anticommutative or graded commutative the diagram 
$$
\begin{matrix}
1_X[p]\wedge 1_X[p']&\buildrel{\sim}\over{\to} & 1_X[p+p']\\
\sigma \downarrow  & &\downarrow (-1)^{p+p'}\\
1_X[p']\wedge 1_X[p]&\buildrel{\sim}\over{\to} & 1_X[p+p'],
\end{matrix}
$$
where $\sigma$ denotes the permutation, must commute. Right?

Comment: I know this is probably frustrating, but I'm not convinced that the kind of commutativity you are asking for is natural. I mean, yes, it'd be nice, but I don't think $S^{a+b}$ knows enough about $a$ and $b$ and $\wedge$ to have useful opinions on that square.

Comment: The sign should be $(-1)^{ab}$. This square is a functorial image of the analogous square in the ordinary stable homotopy category, where the commutativity boils down to computing the degree of reflections on spheres.

Comment: @MarcHoyois wait Marc, I see two problems on your answer. 1.-The functor goes SH->SH^{top}, not the other way around. So it cannot be the functorial image of the ordinary square. 2.- even if it were, on simplicial sets and topological spaces S^q\wedge S^p= S^{p+q} where = means equal as simplicial sets, not just "homotopy equivalent"... Am I right?

Comment: @Tintin Being the homotopy category of a stable model category, $SH(X)$ is tensored over $SH$. The functor $SH\to SH(X)$ I'm talking about is $E\mapsto E\otimes 1_X$. You may define spheres so that the horizontal maps are equalities, why is that a problem?

Comment: It's impossible to answer 1) unless you specify what the horizontal arrows are.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Sorry for my expression. It is not that there was a problem but that I didn't understand. The functor $SH(X)\to SH^{top}$ I was talking about was the one from Riou's "Categorie homotopiquement stable..." but I see you talked of a different one.  I didn't know there was a product of Voevodsky's spectra and simplicial spectra, but that seems reasonable. Could you please give me a reference? I would like to take a look to it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tintin This follows from the universal property of $SH$, a reference for which is [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/higheralgebra.pdf), Cor. 1.4.4.6. More concretely, if you take $T$-$S^1$-prespectra in simplicial presheaves as a model for $SH(X)$, then the functor sending a simplicial spectrum to $\Sigma^\infty_T$ of the corresponding constant presheaf is left Quillen for appropriate model structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Marc Hoyois which pointed the answer in a comment above. I am just writting that with more details:

1.- Yes, the diagram is commutative.

2.- This already happens in classic stable homotopy category. One may find the concrete statement in Adam's *"Stable homotopy and generalised homology"* at the beggining of section III.4   It is not anything particular from the product of spheres $S^n$ but it is a general fact from the smash product of spectra. Since this reference is hard to find in electronic format I copy the page here [image]

(One obtains our diagram of 1 for classic spectra out of the lower right diagram of Adam's page. Note that there is a missprint on the upper right corner, it should be $Y\wedge X$ and not $X\wedge Y$). Thanks everyone for the comments and help.

Comment: Je dirais même plus, oui, le diagramme est commutatif. Je vois que vous n'avez pas quitté la rue du Labrador depuis votre enquête sur le fétiche arumbaya à l'oreille cassée...

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an answer to a question you did not ask; sorry.

The corresponding diagram $T\wedge T\to T\wedge T$ neither commutes nor anticommutes.
An observation of Morel (that was studied in detail in section 16.2. of http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2110) is that $SH(X)[1/2]$ splits into two summands $SH_+(X)\bigoplus SH_-(X)$ such that this diagram is commutative on $SH_+(X)$ and is anticommutative on $SH_-(X)$. The second summand is "often" non-zero and non-torsion. The De Rham cohomology (as well as $-\wedge E_{\mathrm{dR}}$) kills $SH_-(X)$ (since  $E_{\mathrm{dR}}$ is orientable); yet $SH_-(X)$   can be detected by certain Witt cohomology theories.

Comment: The diagram for $a=b=0$ does commute by the axioms for a symmetric monoidal category.

Comment: Sorry; I was thinking about the diagram $T\wedge T\to T\wedge T$. That was stupid of me!